# section size change with collapsible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got multiple divs with working collapsible, I would like to fit them within a section that will change size upon clicking the collapsible, said collapsible is located at the bottom, hence the size change

I have tried a script that changes the section's size upon clicking the collapsible button, only to have not react at all.

```js
var drop = document.getElementsByClassName("drop");
var panel = document.getElementById("panel");
var i;
 
for (i = 0; i < drop.length; i++) {
  drop[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  var collapse = this.previousElementSibling;
  if (collapse.style.maxHeight) {
    collapse.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
    collapse.style.maxHeight = collapse.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
for (i = 0; i < drop.length; i++) {
  drop[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#panel {
 background-color: black;
 float: center;
 position: relative;
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px
}

#box1 {
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}

#box2 {
 background-color: yellow;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 float: right;
}

.drop {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .drop:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.collapse {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: red;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id=panel>
 <div id="box1">
  <br>this is red</br>
  <div class="collapse">
   <p>a drop</p>
  </div>
  <button class="drop">view more</button>
 </div>
 <div id="box2">
  <br>this is yellow</br>
  <div class="collapse">
   <p>a drop</p>
  </div>
  <button class="drop">view more</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

I wanted the whole section to expand downwards upon the collapsible being triggered, instead, nothing happens.

Comment: Moved your code to the snippet editor to help folks reproduce the issue. Did change one minor thing wherein you had getElement**s**ById where Element was plural and would have caused an error. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Having difficulty visualizing what you actually want the result to be and how you want it to behave. Care to clarify a bit? You just want a panel, that when you click something the panel expands downwards?

Comment: what i mean is the panel that expands will have other content under it. at the moment when they collapse, they do it upwards, since they are at the bottom of their divs, i want them to collapse downwards, thus making the div's size increase and the content below will move downwards to make space for the collapsible.